# Compare two months from two different years in a bar chart

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to compare two months in a bar chart, but I want the bars to be next to each other. For example to have January2016 next to January2015, then the same for February etc... I don't know how to do it and I'm curious to know if it's possible.

Thank you

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your X-Axis, use this expression. Just replace `[yourDateColumn]` with what ever it's called in your data:

```
<BinByDateTime([yourDateColumn],"Month",0) NEST BinByDateTime([yourDateColumn],"Year",0)>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help @user3060991